# set htaccess for access to this file Directly

Tags: .htaccess

i want all of file in folder /client/ just available to access by `subdomain.site.com`

to another say i have Some swf(flash) file in folder /client/ For example `/client/1.swf` that if user enter this address in browser: site.com/client/1.swf
he can's access to this file Directly

but i want user just can accessible to `site.com/client/1.swf` address through `subdomain.site.com`

anybody can help me for set htaccess file !?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^client/ - [L,F]
```

If you would rather return a 404 instead of a 403 (forbidden) then change the stuff in the square brackets to: `[L,R=404]`

Comment: i need accessible it for 1 sub domain address and 1 domain address: subdomain.site.com and site2.com , now How?

Comment: @Mehrad Add another rewrite cond line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site2\.com$ [NC]`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to Create an .htaccess file in client. Like `/client/.htaccess` Then put this code.

Apache 2.2

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Apache 2.4

```
Require all denied
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```